# Excel to HTML table

Tags: html, json, excel, html-table, import-from-excel

I'm new to web programming and the first project that i'm working on is a web site that allows the user to see information from an Excel file (which is updated daily). I started from converting the Excel file to JSON with the help of a Youtube tutorial and this library https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.

I have the information that i want converted to objects but I don't know how to use it to show a table in a website. Any suggestions?

This is my current code:

```js
/* set up XMLHttpRequest */
  var url = "Teste.xlsx";
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("GET", url, true);
  oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  oReq.onload = function(e) {
    var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

    /* convert data to binary string */
    var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
    var arr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    var bstr = arr.join("");

    /* Call XLSX */
    var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
      type: "binary"
    });

    /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    //var address_of_cell = 'A1';
    /* Get worksheet */
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
    XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

  }

  oReq.send();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you're over-complicating things a bit.

Excel files can be exported as html files and or you can **EMBED** the excel file into a html file in a number of ways.

1. You could create a live excel file using [office online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx?ui=en%2DUS) Once the excel file is created , go to to the **File** menu, and choose **Share**.  Embed using generated HTML.
2. If you are not confined to excel, you could alternatively  use an iframe with a ["Google Sheets" document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/) created with the data and choose the "Publish to the web" option in the sheet; an embedded [google sheet](http://spreadsheets.google.com) will update to reflect updates.
3. If you are really in a hurry you can convert your file into a HTML table using a tool like [Tableizer](http://tableizer.journalistopia.com/) but I wouldn't recommended this as a learning tool. (this is for future reference)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Rachel and thanks for you help!
But unfortunately i dont know if that could help me. The aplication is not for me to use and the file will be often changed.
Added to showing the table in a website i would like to try after that to create a search engine just to show the information that the user wants to see. That's why im trying to use JSON  so that i can handle the information that i want.

Comment: @BrunoSantos both the live excel sheet and the google sheets will reflect changes made to the spreadsheet. Here, here's a link that explains other options (but not json unfortunately) https://www.labnol.org/software/embed-tables-spreadsheet-data-in-websites/7435/

Comment: I managed to use the solution i wanted, thanks a lot for your 
availability to help :)

Comment: @BrunoSantos I saw the code you used in a later question. Although you still could have done it more easily, well done on finishing your own code successfully (it's always nice when things work out in the end! :) ). Would you mind accepting my answer anyway? It marks it as useful to other people for the future (and we both get rep).. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source conversion script/system available at : https://sourceforge.net/projects/excel-sheet-to-html-table/

which can be used to generate an html table ( with Search and Filter Option ) quickly.